# Flask app delivery calculator function not working

Tags: python, jquery, python-3.x, ajax, flask

I built a simple a delivery calculator form where it calculates the distance coefficient multiplied by distance plus the package weight coefficient multiplied by package weight. Whenever I run the app, it does route me to the index, but I'm not sure if my price formula is wrong or if I'm missing something in my index html? If someone would care to help.

```
#Project/app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/delivery_db'
mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/price', methods=['POST'])
def get_price():
    distance = int(request.form['distance'])
    weight = int(request.form['weight'])
    coefficients = mongo.db.coefficients.find_one()
    distance_coefficient = coefficients['distance_coefficient']
    weight_coefficient = coefficients['weight_coefficient']
    price = distance_coefficient * distance + weight_coefficient * weight
    return jsonify({'price': price})

@app.route('/admin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        distance_coefficient = float(request.form['distance_coefficient'])
        weight_coefficient = float(request.form['weight_coefficient'])
        mongo.db.coefficients.update_one({}, {'$set': {'distance_coefficient': distance_coefficient, 'weight_coefficient': weight_coefficient}})
    coefficients = mongo.db.coefficients.find_one()
    return render_template('admin.html', coefficients=coefficients)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```
#Project/templates/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Delivery Calculator</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form').submit(function(event) {
                // Stop form from submitting normally
                event.preventDefault();
                
                // Get the distance and weight values
                var distance = $('input[name=distance]:checked').val();
                var weight = $('input[name=weight]').val();

                // Send an AJAX POST request to the Flask web service
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/delivery_price',
                    data: {'distance': distance, 'weight': weight},
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Display the delivery price
                        $('#delivery-price').text('$' + response['delivery_price'].toFixed(2));
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Delivery Calculator</h1>
    <form>
        <p>Select the distance:</p>
        <label><input type="radio" name="distance" value="10">10 km</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="distance" value="25">25 km</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="distance" value="50">50 km</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="distance" value="100">100 km</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="distance" value="101">Over 100 km</label><br>

        <p>Enter the package weight:</p>
        <input type="text" name="weight"><br><br>

        <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
    </form>

    <p>Delivery price: <span id="delivery-price"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
Project/static/js/script.js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handle form submission
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get the selected distance and package weight
        var distance = $('input[name=distance]:checked').val();
        var weight = $('#weight').val();

        // Send an AJAX request to the Flask web service to retrieve the delivery price
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/price',
            data: {'distance': distance, 'weight': weight},
            success: function(response) {
                // Display the delivery price
                $('#result').text('Delivery Price: ' + response['price']);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                // Display an error message
                $('#result').text('Error: Unable to retrieve delivery price.');
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I can't seem to figure it out, I' am a very beginner level python developer for reference, and used templates to help me out a little bit.

Comment: Ajax is sending the request to the `delivery_price` address which does not exist, it should be `price`. you can check the request and response from the browser console

Comment: And as I understand you aren't using the `script.js` file, what was the reason for uploading it here? it's a little confusing.